# ionic ble : not able to show the updated ble device name on change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic4

ok so i have created an app using ionic and angular and i want to change the ble device name. For that i am using ionic ble(ble.writeWithNoResponse) [ionic-ble github](https://github.com/don/ionic-ble-examples) but although i am able to change the name. It not getting updated when i try to scan the devices after changing the name.

I downloaded an app from the playstore and when i scan for devices it is showing the updated name.

so the problem i am facing right now is after changing the name from my app and scan the devices my app doesnt show the updated name it still shows the old name...But when i scan from the playstore app and later scan from my app the updated name is shown...

Can anyone explain me the reason behind this? any help would be appreciated!! thanks...

and sorry for my bad English.....

Comment: This is most likely because of caching. On which devices are you running your app?

Comment: Thanks for replying....I'm running it on my android device and even I tried to clear cache of the app but still I have the same issue...

Comment: I found what was the issue actually...The thing is while using ionic ble and try to change the device name....we need to first scan for available devices once before directly connecting to it with its id. Hope it helps for someone.... :)

Comment: Thanks for coming back! You could turn your comment into an answer and accept it so future users will find it better

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the issue actually...The thing is while using ionic ble and try to change the device name....we need to first scan for available devices once before directly connecting to it with its id. Hope it helps for someone.... :)